# PlotStyle a particular curve

Tags: plotting, legending

Let me give an example

```
 pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}];

 Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[a][t], {a, -1, 1, .5}]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

which gives

[image]

How can I set, for example, that only the orange curve be thick. One would think to do

```
PlotStyle->{Default,Thick,Default,Default,Default}
```

But what if we do

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[pfun[a][t], {a, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

and get

[image]

Is there an "elegant" way to give PlotStyle to the curve with `a==0`, for example?

Comment: Add the option `PlotStyle->{Default,Thickness[0.05],Default,Default,Default}`to `Plot`

Comment: @andre Thanks. I edited my question to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[  
    Evaluate[ Table[
       If[-0.01<a<0.01 ,Style[pfun[a][t],Thickness[0.02]],pfun[a][t]],
       {a, -1, 1, .1} 
       ]] ,
    {t, 0, 1},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: I modified your suggestion as `Plot[Evaluate[Table[If[a == 0,Style[pfun[a][t], Thick], Style[pfun[a][t], Dashed]], {a, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1},PlotRange -> All]` to show the curve for `a==0` thick and the other dashed. Thanks

Comment: @resanrom I wouldn't use `a==0` because of some eventual problems of precision.  I think it's safer to use a interval like `-0.01<a<0.01`or `Abs[a]<0.01`. (0.01 or 1E-3 ...1E-6, I don't know)

Comment: If you had used `1/10` instead of `.1` in the step size for `Table[]`, then @resanrom's suggestion would have been reasonable.